# How to display map tips only for one layer?

Tags: qgis, labeling, layers, fields-attributes, maptips

I'm relatively new to QGIS.

I added the hover labels to my map using the Map Tips. My issue is that it makes hover labels for EVERY layer on my map. I only want it to make labels for one layer.

Is there a way to fix this like assigning Map Tips to only apply to one layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am rather new to QGIS as well so there may be a much better way to accomplish map tip suppression for individual layers:

Just made a quick test with v2.8.2 on Windows. From the "Display" page of the layer properties, setting the Map Tip to display to be a field filled with NULL values results in no map tip for that layer.

I also found if the map tip value is a python function that returns no value the map tip is suppressed. What I did:

1. Open layer properties
2. Select *Display* page
3. Enable *HTML* and hit *Insert expression...* button
4. Selecting *Function Editor* showed a scratch area with a template function that takes an argument, does nothing and does not return a value:

   ```
   from qgis.core import *
   from qgis.gui import *

   @qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
   def func(value1, feature, parent):
       pass
   ```
5. Switch back to the *Expression* tab and enter `func(1)` in the expression editor and hit *Ok* to go back to the layer properties _Display" page. The value *1* is not important
6. The HTML map tip display text should be set to `[% func(1)%]`
7. *Ok* to close the layer properties dialog and test Map Tips for that layer. I do not have any on this layer.

Hope this of some help.